# Transform string into IF argument

Tags: string, python-3.x, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

How to transform a string into a logical argument in Python, to be inserted as an argument of the `if()` function?

For example:

```
string = "(A != 0) and (B >= 5)"
```

How can this string be transformed into the very logic that it represents so that it can be inserted into an `if()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the eval function to evaluate the string:

```
string = "(A != 0) and (B >= 5)"
if eval(string):
    doSomething()
```

Comment: it is worth noting that depending on your usage the eval method causes a potential security concern if that string is user provide you're ripe for in injection attack.

Comment: your answer is still right, i'd just evaluate the string first validate a simplistic & conditional structure - perhaps only allow numerics, evaluators (=-+{}[]<>) and single letters (not words) as a starter

Comment: Will this work well if you have arbitary spaces between the characters, or you can have only 1 space between the characters?

Comment: You can have an arbitrary number of spaces, as the function eval will, as the name suggests, evaluate the expression contained in the string.